# Re-querying the table with different values and adding the result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. there is an input parameter. I need to perform a search on the first table, on the second table, and based on the search result on the second table, make a query to the first and output the combined result.

```
first step: 
select * from first table where id = 2
second step:
select * from second table where id = 2; result origid = 222
third step:
select * from first table where secondid = 222
```

first table:

| id | text | secondid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text1 | 123 |
| 2 | text2 | 321 |
| 3 | text3 | 222 |
| 4 | text4 | 101 |

second table:

| id | text | origid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | text1 | 111 |
| 2 | text2 | 222 |
| 30 | text3 | 333 |
| 44 | text4 | 444 |

expected result:

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | text2 |
| 3 | text3 |

Comment: According to your description there should be three result rows (2|text2 from the first table, 2|text2 from the second table, 3|text3 from the first table). I suppose that that description is wrong and you only want to show rows from the first table?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I only need the result from the first table

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query that combines both tables `first_table` and `second_table` using a `subquery` to filter results based on certain conditions.

```
DECLARE @Id int = 2;

SELECT id, text
FROM first_table t1
WHERE id = @Id OR secondid IN (
    SELECT origid
    FROM second_table t2
    WHERE t2.id = t1.id 
);
```

The above query retrieves rows from `first_table` where either the `id` matches the variable `@Id` or where the `secondid` matches an `origid` in the `second_table` based on the conditions specified.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `OR` query as in the other answer. But this sometimes has performance issues. If you do encounter issues (such as a big index scan), you can use a manual Index Union instead.

```sql
DECLARE @Id int = 2;

SELECT id, text
    FROM first_table t1
    WHERE id = @Id

UNION ALL

SELECT id, text
    FROM first_table
    WHERE secondid IN (
        SELECT origid
        FROM second_table t2
        WHERE t2.id = @Id
    );
```

If you could possibly get the same row twice then you need to change `UNION ALL` to `UNION`. Otherwise use `UNION ALL` as it is more efficient.

Comment: I have performance issues. the request is not being executed

Comment: You need the right indexes. Please show tables and index definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com